# What does words[count] = stars mean

Tags: python

I'm a beginner and I did an exercise on Codecademy and the solution was this:

```
    def censor(text, word):

       words = text.split()
       result = ''
       stars = '*' * len(word)
       count = 0
       for i in words:
         if i == word:
            words[count] = stars
         count += 1
       result =' '.join(words)

       return result
```

So my questions is what does *words[count] = stars* in line 8 mean?

Comment: it is replacing the position of "word" in your words with stars

Comment: I... I don't even know what to say here... This is pretty self-explanatory. `words` is a list, `count` is an index. `=` is the assignment operator.

Comment: It is iterating through every word, then if that is word it needs to be censored, it will replace the word that it is looking at with the *.

Comment: wouldn't call this a 'solution'. This is one: `return ' '.join('*' * len(w) if w == word else w for w in text.split())`.

Comment: Naming a string `i` and an index `count` is a bit confusing. The index should have been named `i` and the string `word`.

Answer (score 0):

It assigns the result of dereferencing the local variable `stars` to be the element of the list referenced by the local variable `words` at the index obtained by dereferencing the local variable `count`.

Comment: Could the downvoter explain what is wrong with my answer? I am not a Python expert, merely a casual user, so is there something I overlooked? Some terminology I got wrong? (I am more comfortable with Ruby and Scala terminology.)

Answer (score -1):

The line `words[count] = stars` is an assignment.

On the right hand side of the equal sign you find the value that you want to assign to something. In this case it's a string or sequence of characters of the form `******`.

On the left hand side of the equal sign is the target of the assignment. It is where you want to store the sequence of chars. In this case the target is a position in the list `words`. The position is specified by `count`.

Thus, if you had the current state

```
words = ['Hello', 'World']
count = 1
stars = '*****'
```

then the assignment in line 8 would result in the following state:

```
words = ['Hello', '*****']
```

It has assigned the new value `*****` of `stars` to the position `count` in the list `words` and by that replaced `World`.